# Using Databricks CLI command output in other Unix command

Tags: bash, azure, command-line-interface, databricks, databricks-cli

I am using Databricks CLI to configure clusters and setup libraries in Azure Release pipeline as part of an Azure CLI task with **/bin/bash as the interpreter**. At one place, I am trying to use databricks fs ls command to list a jar file in a dbfs path which matches a specific file name pattern and store the name of that file in a unix variable.

```
databricks fs ls dbfs:/fs/jars/*<pattern>*.jar --profile <profile_name>
```

This code fails as dbfs ls expects only a directory as argument, and not files patterns.

I tried others combinations like:

```
grep *<pattern>*.jar < <(databricks fs ls dbfs:/fs/jars/ --profile <profile_name>)
```

and

```
grep *<pattern>*.jar | cat < <(databricks fs ls dbfs:/fs/jars/ --profile <profile_name>)
```

but to no avail.

However, the command

```
cat < <(databricks fs ls dbfs:/fs/jars/ --profile <profile_name>
```

works fine stand alone.

Question is : how to use unix commands in conjunction with databricks CLI commands?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a pipe (`|`) operation to forward output of databricks-cli into other commands:

```sh
databricks fs ls dbfs:/fs/jars/ --profile <profile_name>|grep <your-pattern>
```